# .NET Socket or port forwarding issue?

Tags: .net, sockets, portforwarding

I have this problem with the application I'm coding right now.

I'm coding a server and client application using Sockets .NET. The server runs on a machine with a static IP of 192.168.1.6. The client has no problem connecting to that IP address over LAN. But when I set up the client to connect to my WAN IP, the connection could not be made.

Of course I immediately thought of port forwarding, so I configured my router to accept incoming connections on the port I use for the application and the machines static IP. I even checked if the port was correctly forwarded using the PFPortChecker tool by portforward.com (and it was), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?
I really hope somebody can help me out, because I'm literally pulling out my last hairs now...

EDIT:

Ok, I've narrowed the problem down to a .NET Socket issue.
Basically when I try to connect with the following code (C#):

```
Socket _client;

_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_client.Connect("XX.XXX.XXX.X", XXXX);
```

The connection could only be made within a LAN environment. 
however, when I have an instance of the server running on my machine, and I try to ping the WAN IP and port using the PFPortChecker tool, I actually get a response in my server, and it starts to handle the incoming connection as a new client.

Any idea how I can fix my code so the connection can be made over WAN?

EDIT 2:

Ok, so I figured out what the problem was. I am not able to connect from my own WAN IP to my own WAN IP. On another network I have no problem connecting to my server.

Thanks for your trouble anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would first recommend running Wireshark on the server, to see if he is seeing the incoming connections. That will confirm whether or not the router is forwarding traffic on that port to the machine or not.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to run Wireshark on the client, too, to check that the request is going to the WAN address.

Comment: I ran wireshark, using the filter tcp.port == XXXX (where XXXX is the port I use), but nothing came up. I once read somewhere that an application could not connect to it's own WAN address. Is that true, or is there another reason I'm not getting any packages? EDIT: commencing wireshark on client, let's see if that gives me anything to work with...

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the same machine? That makes it more confusing, but not impossible. If your public IP is 1.2.3.4, and you try to connect to 1.2.3.4, the packet should go out, hit your router on the WAN side, who will turn around and send it back in to 192.168.1.6

Comment: No, at the moment I'm using a PC to run the server, and a laptop to run the client. Works just as well as when I debug both applications on the same pc. EDIT: Ok, well at least wireshark tells me that the client is sending the packages to my WAN IP. I guess this leaves the problem at receiving the packages. Strange though, because as it seems to me this is a port forwarding issue, and the PFPortChecker tool told me that it could ping the WAN IP and requested port.

Comment: I know I'm not programming in c++ but in c#, but could this be a reason for the problem I'm having? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/70005/#msg376337 If so, how can I apply this solution to c# (I mean the htonl(INADDR_ANY); part)?

Comment: Almost all routers will not allow loopback connections to the external IP from inside the local subnet.  To test external access you need to be outside your network.

Comment: @Joe, I've ran a webserver behind three different routers and never seen this behavior. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The problem is not running the webserver.  The problem is trying to route to the WAN side IP from the LAN behind the *same* router.  This local loopback is not supported by many setups.

Comment: @Joe, I understand what you are saying. But I have a webserver behind my router at home, in DMZ. I have a domain that points to my router's WAN IP. I can successfully go to my own website (by domain); always have been able to.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.6 is a LAN subnet ... your external IP is different. If port forwarding is fine than that's probably the problem. Google "what's my ip" and it should tell you your external ip address

Comment: Not to be a dick or something, but those who don't know the difference between LAN IP and WAN IP should not meddle with Socket programming.